# lint failing on code line where function is called as parameter passed from other function Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I have a function where it passes two params to other function (one of them is function name):

```
sendSomething(){
this.responseWithModal(this.responseType, this.openModal());
}

responseWithModal(response, successFunction){
this.store.dispatch(sendResponse(payload: {something}));
successFunction;
}

successFunction(){
window.open("www.somelink.com");
}
```

When I am running `npm run lint` it can not pass linting and gets error:

> unused expression, expected an assignment or function call

The thing is that everything works as expected, but I can not pass lint because of that fail for `successFunction;` call in `responseWithModal()` function. Maybe there is better solution how to solve function as parameter calling?

Comment: you are not calling the function, it should be `successFunction();` and not `successFunction;`

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems, which aren't necessarily immediately obvious because you're not using types, which you should.

The first issue is that

```
sendSomething(){
  this.responseWithModal(this.responseType, this.openModal());
}
```

should be

```
sendSomething(){
   this.responseWithModal(this.responseType, this.openModal);
}
```

i.e., you shouldn't invoke the function here, just pass the function to the method

Then,

```
responseWithModal(response, successFunction){
  this.store.dispatch(sendResponse(payload: {something}));
  successFunction;
}
```

should be

```
responseWithModal(response, successFunction){
  this.store.dispatch(sendResponse(payload: {something}));
  successFunction();
}
```

i.e. you **should** invoke the function here

Comment: That was the first try for implementing such functionality. The thing is that after such call, all variables and observables initialized during ngOnInit() are marked as undefined and in such case I get error that I am using undefined values in my mentioned successFunction() call.

Comment: Sounds like you have other issues elsewhere, and this is just a symptom.

Comment: Yes, when passing function as parameter, I was not binding scope to the function I pass `this.openModal.bind(this)`